# Retrieving another user's information Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve another user's info from parse.com.  I need to get the "Location" that is part of the parse object that the user would have put in when they sign up.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // String user = mCurrentUser.getObjectId();
    Object o = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
    String user = (String) o; 
    final ParseObject newUser = mUser.getParseObject(user);
    String objId = newUser.getObjectId();


    query.getInBackground(objId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // String str = (String)
                // ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("Location");
                Object o = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                String str = (String) o; 
                String loc = (String) newUser.get("Location");
                Toast.makeText(Friends.this, "Location of " + str + " is " + loc,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I am trying to retrieve the users object ID but for some reason it cannot seem to get the users Location.

**UPDATE**: From one of the comments below I debugged and `String o` is definitely returning a string.  I would put a bounty on this, but I do not have enough rep...

Line 127 is:

```
final ParseObject newUser = mUser.getParseObject(user);
```

The logcat:

```
    09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912): Process: com.kooknluke.wingman, PID: 24912
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at com.kooknluke.wingman.Friends.onListItemClick(Friends.java:127)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1478)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3480)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4823)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-14 18:07:56.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The callback must throw you an exception or error message. Look in your LogCat and see what it says and post it in your question.

Comment: okay so what is on line 127?

Comment: line 127 is at the top of the logcat like i said

Comment: Then (obviously) either that line is producing a `NullPointerException`... are you sure that `String user = (String) o;` actually produces a `String`?

Comment: Yeah, I used the exact same method in another part of the app and it works fine.

Comment: Assert mUser not null @ 127

Comment: After debugging more, mUser is null but I don't know why.  I declared it as `ParseUser mUser = new ParseUser();`